# Running Vagrant VM on Ubuntu 20.04 VM on VirtualBox on Windows 11 Host Machine, Need SSH access to vagrant from windows 11

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machines, vagrant

I am doing a computer vision project, and I have Vagrant VM on Ubuntu 20.04 VM on VirtualBox on Windows 11 Host Machine. I'd like to use the Windows 11 host machine for the CV since it needs a lot of processing power, and communicate with a python app in vagrant currently running using SSH, since it's not a very resource intensive app.

I have a port forwarded (8000 -> 8000) in virtual box to access the web interface of the app I need, and I can access it from my browser on Firefox in Windows 11.

The problem arises when I attempt to ssh into vagrant (2222->2222) putty gives an error for connection refused, windows cmd gives "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection aborted"

I've tried getting private key, I've tried all variants of ssh commands that I could find, but it's simply not working. Inside Ubuntu I am able to simply type "vagrant ssh" and it will connect to the ssh without any delay.

Am I missing something?

I usually use WSL2 for programming in linux, but my particular application requires that it runs in vagrant in ubuntu.

[port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkThn.png)

[vagrant ssh-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ThbS.png)

```
  config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu2010"

  # Publically forwarded ports.
  # The below ports are accessible to all machines on the same network.
  # To limit access to the local network, add "host_ip".
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  # Eg: config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000 # Web App
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000 # Remote server
  #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2222, host: 2222 # Remote server #<--this is commented because it didn't work, and vagrant's startup already specifies that it's forwarding port 22 to port 2222.
  #config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp" #<-- so is this
  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.password = 'test'
  config.ssh.insert_key = 'false'
```

[Vagrant's Startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mr4C.png)

Nevermind, I'm an idiot. Installed openssh in ubuntu and was able to access vagrant.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question, as written, doesn't seem to be a question as it contains its own resolution. If you would like to answer your own question, then please edit this question so it only contains a question, and then provide an answer with all applicable steps to resolve the issue. Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer), and don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).